# Can I measure 220 V AC signal by spectrum analyzer ?

Tags: noise, mains, spectrum-analyzer

I want to observe noise in mains voltage. Can I measure 220 V AC signal by spectrum analyzer to observe noise? My spectrum analyzer GSP-830. Thanks!

Comment: 0
down vote
 

You might wanna use a LISN. Check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Impedance_Stabilization_Network

Comment: @Mikey A LISN 1) does not provide proper **mains isolation** 2) filters the mains voltage to prevent them getting to the DUT, that filtering removes the noise OP wants to see! 3) just isn't intended for what OP wants.

Comment: How come certification labs use a LISN for conducted emissions then?

Comment: @Mikey They would use an **isolation transformer** for safety. so: Mains => isolation transformer => LISN <= DUT  the Spectrum analyzer is then also connected to the LISN. The difference is that with a LISN you measure the emissions of the DUT, not the noise on the mains. You don't even want the mains noise to get through as that would disturb the measurement. So the mains transformer actually helps as it will filter some noise.

Comment: For an oscilloscope, high voltage probes exist. However a Spectrum analyzer will have a 50 ohm input. I have not seen any high voltage adapters capable of driving 50 ohms

Comment: There are special voltage probes with isolation used for scopes to measure mains signals, for instance within a power supply. You may use such a probe if it has the input range for 230 V AC and the bandwidth needed to measure the noise you want to observe. Read the datasheet and specification about isolation and input range as well as bandwidth.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie LISN provides a 50 ohm output impedance. https://www.com-power.com/datasheets/LI-150A.pdf  Application: Power line conducted emissions tests. In addition: please read https://incompliancemag.com/article/guide-to-testing-conducted-emissions-based-on-the-methods-in-en-55022-and-en-55011/ PART LISNs, AMNs and V-Networks

Comment: Try making a capacitive or magnetic probe. You can see the spectral content, but accurate amplitude measuremetns can not be done.

Comment: @Mikey *LISN provides a 50 ohm output impedance* I never denied that, how does that 50 ohms output on a LISN relate to **any** of the issues I brought up regarding using a LISN for what OP wants? Only if the **neutral** is grounded in your building can a LISN be OK to use. That still doesn't make a LISN the ideal option for OP.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to observe noise in mains voltage.

And

> My spectrum analyzer GSP-830.

The lowest frequency that the GSP-830 can measure is 9 kHz so, from your limited details I would say it may not be suitable because it will not be able to measure the first 150 harmonics.

The device also has a limited input amplitude range: -

> Overload Protection   Max. +30dBm, ±25VDC

It's also got an input impedance of 50 ohms.

If you still wish to proceed then more details are required but, it is highly likely that some form of isolation barrier will be needed to prevent electrocution or destroying the GSP-830.